# Suggestion on creation app for getting information from webpage

Tags: python, browser

First want to say that I have experience with python and some web libraries like mechanize, beautiful soup, urllib2.

The idea is to create an app that will grab information from webpage, that I currently looking on in webbrowser. And than store it.

For example:
I manually go to the website, create a user.
Than run my app, that will grab some details from webpage, that I'm currently looking on. like user name, first name, last name and so on.

Problems:
I don't know how to make a program to run kinda on top of my webbrowser. I can't simply make a scipt to login to this webpage and do the rest with Beautiful Soup because it has a very good protection from web-crawlers and web bots.

Need some place to start. So the main question is is it possible to grab information that currently on my web browser? if yes hope to hear some suggestions on how to make my program look at the browser?

Please fill free to ask me if you not kinda understand what I'm asking, or you have some suggestions, some libraries that I can use.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or if you want a visual tool you could look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Fake](http://fakeapp.com/).

Comment: PhantomJS looks very nice, will take a look at it, thank you

Comment: The problem with PhantomJS is that I don't think you can do much manually, since it's headless. Of course it might be easier to do the scripting there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is probably to save the HTML content of the current page to a file (using File -> Save Page As or whatever it is in your browser) and then running Beautiful Soup / lxml.html / whatever on that file.

You could probably also get [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to do what you want, though I've never used it and am not sure.

Comment: I was thinking about this also, but want to create an app that will do it automatically. Do you know is it possible to take current web page from browser cache?

Comment: Also about Selenium, is it possible to do login part manually and than call selenium and do the rest?